# IOS UI Automation - working with external Data

Tags: javascript, ios7, xcode5, ios-ui-automation

Is there any way to work with external Data, for example Textfiles ?
With JS there isn´t any option to do I/O, for a good reason.
The purpose is, that i want to validate data from a file or a database with the data represented in the APP (comparison tests)…
Is there any trick for the UI Automation tool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Text file

This is something I came up with based on [`performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIAutomation/Reference/UIAHostClassReference/UIAHost/UIAHost.html) method:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var host = target.host();
var result = host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout(
                     "/bin/cat", ["/Users/username/Documents/test.txt"], 5)

var content = result.stdout;
UIALogger.logMessage(content);
```

Content of the `test.txt`:

> Hello World!
>   This is a test.

And this is how it looks in the *Editor Log*:

[image]

The downside is that you'll have to manually parse file's content.

### Database

The only feasible option I can see, is to use this same method in conjunction with [Command Line Shell For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html). But, alas, I haven't tried this approach, so I can't guarantee it'll work.